# What is the range and success rate on the Arc Thrower?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

I'm ready to capture my first Alien, but I'm not certain what the range and success rate of the Arc Thrower is. I'm playing on Ironman, so I can't really afford to experiment to find out in the middle of combat. I don't want to get face-to-face with an Alien only to realize I can't capture it unless I damage it some more.

What is the range and success rate on the Arc Thrower?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The range of the Arc Thrower is up to 2 squares. If your target has more than 3 health, the success chance is very low.

Per [wikia](http://xcom.wikia.com/wiki/Arc_Thrower_%28item%29), capture rates are:

- 4 HP : 49% chance for success
- 3 HP : 70% chance for success
- 2 HP : 80% chance for success
- 1 HP : 90% chance for success

Once you have the upgraded ARC Thrower, the capture rates are:

- 7 HP : 49% chance for success
- 6 HP : 70% chance for success
- 5 HP : 75% chance for success
- 4 HP : 80% chance for success
- 3 HP : 85% chance for success
- 2 HP : 90% chance for success
- 1 HP : 95% chance for success

Comment: My favourite capture tactic so far is to get a unit with an arc thrower into cover, within one move of the target, then to damage the target with a second unit. A lot of the earlier targets are weak, so switching to a pistol helps to avoid killing it outright.

Comment: The *Disabling Shot* skill of the sniper class is very handy for capturing, because it allows the soldiers with the arc throwers to approach the target safely. The *Suppression* skills of the Heavy and Support classes also prevent enemies from shooting, unless the shot is a very easy one.

Comment: In my experience, the capture rate for >3 HP has always been 49%

Comment: well as you progress on. i think capturing the elite mutons and ethereal will be hard. but if you got the research up till Ghost Armor it will be damn easy :D

Comment: Capturing Mutons is a great way to stock up on Plasma Rifles to save you some much needed Elenium and Alloys.  
http://xcom.wikia.com/wiki/Muton